# dependency injection and what is this class?

Tags: android

I'm learning android architecture pattern specifically MVVM,
I see examples of it. often I see people use dependency injection and almost the code has class that extended from Application class I want to understand its purpose and want to know the using of dependency injection.

[Example of the class](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvvm-architecture/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mindorks/framework/mvvm/MvvmApp.java):

```
public class MvvmApp extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {

@Inject
DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;

@Inject
CalligraphyConfig mCalligraphyConfig;

@Override
public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
    return activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()
            .inject(this);

    AppLogger.init();

    AndroidNetworking.initialize(getApplicationContext());
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        AndroidNetworking.enableLogging(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    }

    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(mCalligraphyConfig);
}
```

}

Comment: Have you checked it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection

Comment: I'm trying to understand the purpose of using it,
Edit: Thank your for the link I will check it now

Comment: The link I have provided, will let you know the purpose of using it.